# What is the meaning of SKETCH(1:1B) in NX?

Tags: vb.net, definition

good evening, recently I am using the latest version NX 12 via visual basics, and I have encountered a column of code which I couldn't understand, can anyone explain to me what it means?

I've imported the NXOpen library

And here is the column which I didn't understand

`Dim datumCsys1 As NXOpen.Features.DatumCsys = CType(workPart.Features.FindObject("SKETCH(1:1B)"), NXOpen.Features.DatumCsys)`

Also another column which I didn't understand is

`Dim datumAxis1 As NXOpen.DatumAxis = CType(workPart.Datums.FindObject("SKETCH(1:1B) X axis"), NXOpen.DatumAxis)`

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The `workPart.Features.FindObject("SKETCH(1:1B)")` code returns an object, which has the name "SKETCH(1:1B)" in the part navigator - in your case it's a sketch (this can also be a datum plane, axis, feature, ...).

The "Sketch" object has a datum csys object (which has three datum planes YZ, XZ, XY), and three datum axis objects (X, Y, Z) - so the first "line" you provided returns the datum csys, and the second "line" returns the X axis of your work part.

Answer (score 0):

In nx there journal identifiers are assign to each object. `SKETCH(1:1B)` is either journal identifier or the name of feature which you wanted